# How can i constrain a variable to specific allowable values?

Tags: groovy, types

In Groovy, is there some equivalent to string literal types in Typescript:

```
type Choices = 'choice 1' | 'choice 2'
Choices input
```

Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact equivalent of TypeScript's string literal types (at least not in the same terms as defined [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html)). However, with some small amount of code you can make enums to do something pretty similar to them (not exact behavior, but it might actually work for you).

Consider the following example:

```groovy
enum Choices {
    CHOICE_1("choice 1"),
    CHOICE_2("choice 2")

    String literal

    private Choices(String literal) {
        this.literal = literal
    }

    static Choices of(String literal) {
        Choices choices = values().find { it.literal == literal }
        if (choices == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Choices with literal ${literal} is not supported!")
        }
        return choices
    }
}

Choices input = Choices.of("choice 2")

println input.literal // prints "choice 2"
println input // prints "CHOICE_2"

Choices choice = "CHOICE_1" // coerces String to enums name (but not literal!)

println choice.literal // prints "choice 1"
println choice // prints "CHOICE_1"

Choices.of("asdasd") // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: I'd also recommend enums. Groovy is also extensible so you could autogenerate the above enum code fairly easily using an AST transform and or you could use Strings but augment the typechecker, e.g. see:
https://speakerdeck.com/paulk/groovy-roadmap?slide=24
But both probably overkill for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called Enums.

```
enum MyColors{
  BLUE, RED, WHITE
}

println MyColors.values()
```

http://grails.asia/groovy-enum-examples